# How to get EditValue from RepositoryItemsLookUpEdit

Tags: c#, devexpress

How to get `EditValue` which is unique and Binded using `DataSource` `ValueMember` with `RepositoryItemLookUpEdit` in `gridColumn` and on changing value fill the other fields retrieved from database.

Comment: You can use the GridView.GetRowCellValue method to get corresponding value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the `RepositoryItemLookUpEdit's EditValueChanged` event, in which you can obtain the current editor's value

```
 private void repositoryItemLookUpEdit1_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   object value = (sender as LookUpEdit).EditValue;
   /// your code here
 }
```